# Logging IP Address in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, ip-address, nlog

I'm using NLog in my WCF service and would like to log the caller IP-Address.

I've tried using the aspnet-LayoutRenderers (`${aspnet-request:serverVariable=remote_host}`, `${aspnet-request:serverVariable=remote_addr}`, but to no avail, as an internal NLog exception is being thrown and no log file is being generated.

Is there a way to log the IP Address in a WCF service, without needing to pass it as a parameter to the called method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var msg = OperationContext.Current
          .IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

var address = msg.Address;
```